# Implementing Parses' channel logic with Amazon SNS

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, push, amazon-sns

On Parse (that I now have to leave behind) I had the ability to set multiple channels per installation and then target specific ones in my push notifications.
What is the best way to do this with SNS? At first I thought about topics, but there is a limitation to these.Another problem with topics is that the topic has to pre exist: On Parse you just mentioned a channel and you could then query and filter the Push recipients.

Should I create a similar experience manually using DynamoDB and keep the device token (as a primary key) and then the subscribed channels? This way when I want to send custom push messages I will have to query DB for the specific devices that contain that channel?

Hope someone has already dealt with this before.